# Parsing Strings into Dates

Tags: java

Well i have some doubts in this program...the code is below...doubts are -

1. What is parsing of date and time means ?
2. How can args[] have length ?
3. What does it mean in if statement args.length ==0?"1818-11-11": args[0]; ?

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String input = args.length == 0 ? "1818-11-11" : args[0];
        System.out.print(input + " Parses as ");
        Date t;
        try {
            t = ft.parse(input);
            System.out.println(t);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Unparseable using " + ft);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a step back and read a decent introductory book to Java.

Comment: at least tell me the 3rd one

Comment: 0: At least please do some research effort, 1: [Parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing), 2: see @jb-nizet answer, 3: [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Answer (score 1):

When you start a Java program, you can pass it arguments:

```
java com.foo.Test a b c d
```

In the above example, a, b, c and d are 4 arguments to the program. The main method has access to these arguments in the `args` array passed to the main method by Java.

```
String input = args.length == 0 ? "1818-11-11" : args[0];
```

uses the ternary operator. It's equivalent to

```
String input;
if (args.length == 0) {
    input = "1818-11-11";
}
else {
    input = args[0];
}
```

`args.length` is the length of the array `args`. It it equals 0, then it means that the array is empty, i.e. no argument was passed to the Java program.

This is extremely basic stuff that your tutorial or introductory Java book must cover.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Answer (score 0):

```
What is parsing of date and time means ?
```

It means you are given a date in string and you want the given Date as Object then you use the parse() method of [SimpleDateForamt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition))

**Note** - You cannot expect to parse a date with a SimpleDateFormat that is set up with a different format.

```
How can args[] have length ?
```

Since it is an array so obviously it will have length. Refer [command-line argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)

The third question has already been answered above